# Leaflet : Draw circle always visible and centered even after a move or zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to draw a circle on my Leaflet Map that should be always visible and centered even when user move or zoom in the map.
The following code works well when user move the map, but when the user zoom in or zoom out, the size of the circle is not updated. I would like to keep always the same dimension for the circle.

**HTML**

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="height:75vh;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
// Init Leaflet Map basically
this.map = L.map("map").setView([38.63, -90.23], 12);
window.map = this.map;
this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
   maxZoom: 20,
   maxNativeZoom: 18,
   attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
});

this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);

// Create circle that will be always visible and will have alwaus the same width.
this.circle = L.circle([38.63, -90.23], 3000, {
  color: '#5d78ff',
  fillOpacity: 0
}).addTo(this.map);

// Set circle always centered when map is moved.
this.map.on("moveend", (s) => {
  this.circle.setLatLng(this.map.getCenter());
});

// todo: Set circle always centered when map is zoom in/out
this.map.on("zoomend", (s) => {
  this.circle.setLatLng(this.map.getCenter());
  console.log('test');
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/4uorasdn/

Comment: In the example you provided, the circle does technically stay the same size. When you zoom in, of course it appears bigger. Can you be clearer about what you want? Is it that you want the map to zoom in but the circle should not be affected by the zoom? So that from the user perspective the circle always has the same radius even though the underlying map covers less area as you zoom in?

Comment: @ToddChaffee Yes, it's exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CircleMarker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#circlemarker) instead of using Circle.

The relevant part of your code that needs to be changed should look something like this.

```
this.circle = L.circleMarker([38.63, -90.23], {
  radius: 200,
  color: '#5d78ff',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  opacity: 1,
  title: "test"   
}).addTo(this.map);
```

And you can [find a working jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ajnw4rk/).